# Why does ifstream change its state when reading Doubles in C++?

Tags: c++, file, input, file-io, io

I am writing a method that reads items from a file that is formatted like this:

[String] [Integer] [Double]

[String] [Integer] [Double]

I am reading from the file and storing each line into a vector as a user-defined type using the following loop:

```
 while(ifs.good()){
    Car car;
    ifs >> car.carName;
    ifs >> car.yearBuilt;
    if(!ifs.good()) throw std::invalid_argument("Year must be a integer");
    ifs >> car.price; 
    if(!ifs.good()) 
      throw std::invalid_argument("Price must be a double");
    to_return.push_back(car);
  }
```

However, despite a properly formatted file with the right fields, the function keeps throwing an error saying "Price must be a double". Here is a test file that I used:

Mercedes 1998 2364.12

Audi 2012 32645.79

If I delete the if statement, the file is parsed correctly and the vector works as intended. I am confused on why this error is being thrown and why the file state fixes itself if it is in the fail() state after parsing the double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.good()` is the wrong thing to check for streams a lot of the time, because it also checks whether the `eof` flag is set, i.e. whether the end of the file has been reached by some previous operation.

Normally, reading a `double` wouldn't set the `eof` flag, because text files are supposed to end with a `\n`, so we would find a newline character instead of the EOF while reading.
However, not every text file is properly terminated (including yours, apparently), and we run into the EOF while reading `2364.12`.

Ideally, your code should be able to handle text files that don't end in a newline character.
If we do error handling correctly, this is possible.
Most of the time, you should:

1. try to perform some I/O operation
2. check whether `.fail()` is set to see if it succeeded

C++ streams can be contextually converted to `bool`, which checks the `.fail()` flag implicitly.
As a result, we can write:

```cpp
 // while(true) because at this point, we have done nothing yet
 // and don't have any loop condition we can check.
 // do-while loops also don't make sense when files are properly terminated.
 while(true) {
    Car car;
    if (!(ifs >> car.carName)) {
        // no more cars in stream,
        // we end the loop gracefully
        break;
    }
    if (!(ifs >> car.yearBuilt)) {
        // we've failed reading in the middle of the car's information
        // this is not okay
        throw std::invalid_argument("Failed to read year built");
    }
    if (!(ifs >> car.price)) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Failed to read car price");
    }
    to_return.push_back(car);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in my view, if you want to read `car` objects from a file, it's better to overload `operator>>` for `car` objects:

```cpp
struct car {
    std::string carName;
    int yearBuilt;
    double price;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, car &c) { 
        car temp;
        is >> temp.carName >> temp.yearBuilt >> temp.price;
        if (is) 
            c = temp;
        return is;
    }
};
```

With this, you can read a vector of car objects with code like this:

```cpp
std::vector<car> cars{ std::istream_iterator<car>(ifs), {}};
```